# why does monodevelop need the .NET 3.5 framework to run on windows?

Tags: .net, windows, monodevelop

it's kind of absurd(i think).
mono want to be a substitute to .NET, so why can't i run monodevelop with mono itself?
why do i need .NET for that?

you can see what i'm talking about in this link:
http://monodevelop.com/Download
just choose MonoDevelop 2.2 Beta 1
then choose windows and you will see :-)

thanks :-)

Comment: Have you actually tried it with mono? Is it refusing to run without the Microsoft .NET Framework implementation?

Answer (score 8):

It's because monodevelop for windows is not just plain crossplatform port but something that takes deeper advantage of underlying operation system. There are some features developers wanted/needed to support under Windows and Mono was too constraining for them at this time (however it might and probably will change in the future).

I actually praise developers for doing what's right for their product and not religiously trying to make their software work with Mono on every platform. if Microsoft .NET framework allows them to deliver on Windows better IDE now, then they got my thumbs up.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* run MD it with Mono on Windows. However, we shipped it as an installer for .NET because that's easier for the vast majority of users. Most people have .NET, and on Windows it's better-optimized and more stable than Mono. Providing an installer for MD to run on Mono on Windows would not be an efficient use of our resources at this time, but that's certainly not to say we won't do it in future.